# Two models with an association of have_one to have_many possible in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, ruby-on-rails-3.1, associations

I am making a rails site where you can schedule an appointment for a service. Currently I have an Appointment and Client model. Now I have decided that in order to get the Client's information (name, email, etc) from an Appointment object, I would make an association between the two models. Now the way I see it, an Appointment should `have_one` client and a Client should `have_many` appointments. However, I have never seen an association between two model where they both have `have_x` associations. So what I am wondering is this is possible, will it work? Also is there a better way to do this, maybe something I'm missing? Any insight would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe that will work. You may want to use the `belongs_to` method to associate your `Appointment` to your `Client`:

```
class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client
end

class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
end
```

Answer (score 0):

A `Client` `has_many` `:appointments` and an `Appointment` `belongs_to` a `:client`